# full address resolve to google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

geocode, only allow enter of specify location example like 'building name' , 'city' ..etc . anyway to allow user to enter "**full address (included block number, postal code, street name)**" and it auto resolve to google map location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get the co-ordinates
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=154+Metro+Central+Heights+London+UK&sensor=true
I have set up a demo [here](http://tallymobile.com/test5.html).
In my case the address being 154 Metro Central Heights London UK, google returns the following co-ordinates.

```
"geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 51.5001524,
        "lng": -0.1262362
      }
```

The co-ordinates obtained from the JSON can be used to create a marker on the map in the following way

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                       myOptions);
```